# How to get the "Save Card Details" option from stripe's paymentSheet?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment sheet to pay in my app, but for some reason the payment sheet does not have the "save card details" option as it does in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCx7a.png). The code below works for generating the payment sheet, but there is no option to (1) select previously stored cards or (2) to store the new card they input with the checkbox at the bottom.

```
try {
  // send payment request to server
  const response = await fetch('[redacted]/payment', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          amount,
          name: 'Test User',
          email: 'test@test.com',
          phone: '1234567890',
          
      }),
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  if(!response.ok) return Alert.alert('Something went wrong', data.message);

  const {clientSecret, success, message, ephemeralKey, ret_error, customer} = data;
  console.log("client secret:", clientSecret);
  console.log("success:", success);
  console.log("message:", message);
  console.log("ephemeralKey:", ephemeralKey);
  console.log("error:", ret_error);
  console.log("customer:", customer);
 

  const { init_error } = await initPaymentSheet({
      customerId: customer,
      customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
      paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
      customFlow: false,
      merchantDisplayName: '[redacted]',
      style: 'automatic',
      
      
  });

  if (init_error) {
  console.error(init_error);
  return Alert.alert(init_error.message);
  }

  const { present_error } = await presentPaymentSheet();
  if (!present_error) {
  //Alert.alert('Success', 'The payment was confirmed successfully');
  // fullfill order (TODO: transfer electricity)
  } else if (present_error.error.code === PaymentSheetError.Failed) {
  Alert.alert(
      `PaymentSheet present failed with error code: ${present_error.error.code}`,
      present_error.error.message
  );
  } else if (present_error.error.code === PaymentSheetError.Canceled) {
  Alert.alert(
      `PaymentSheet present was canceled with code: ${present_error.error.code}`,
      present_error.error.message
  );
  }
}
  catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create the PaymentIntent on server-side, make sure to **not** specify `setup_future_usage` to make this option appear on PaymentSheet.

Stripe iOS SDK [documented](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#save-payment-methods-on-payment) it in their CHANGELOG.

Comment: Hi @orakaro ,you haved saved my day!!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi - I am fighting with this right now.  I do not have setup_future_usage in my reqbody server side.  But, the checkbox is still not showing.  Any other tips?