# Cant get 'save payment' checkbox to show for @stripe/stripe-react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo, stripe-payments

I can't get the 'save payment' checkbox to show for @stripe/stripe-react-native paymentSheet.  I am running through expo. I have a backend enpoint up as a firebase function that does this:

```
try {
        const theReqBody = JSON.parse(request.body);
        const paymentIntent = await stripeClient.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: theReqBody.amount * 100,  // pennies
            customer: theReqBody.customerId, // cus_xxx
            currency: 'usd',
            automatic_payment_methods: {
                enabled: true
            },
        });
        response.json({paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret});
    } catch (e) {
        response.status(400).json({
            error: e.message
        })
    }
```

And is returning what looks like a valid intent to me.

```
paymentIntent {
>    id: 'pi_xxxx',
>    object: 'payment_intent',
>    amount: 599,
>    amount_capturable: 0,
>    amount_details: { tip: {} },
>    amount_received: 0,
>    application: null,
>    application_fee_amount: null,
>    automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true },
>    canceled_at: null,
>    cancellation_reason: null,
>    capture_method: 'automatic',
>    client_secret: 'pi_xxxx',
>    confirmation_method: 'automatic',
>    created: 1680557042,
>    currency: 'usd',
>    customer: 'cus_xxxxxxx',
>    description: null,
>    invoice: null,
>    last_payment_error: null,
>    latest_charge: null,
>    livemode: false,
>    metadata: {},
>    next_action: null,
>    on_behalf_of: null,
>    payment_method: null,
>    payment_method_options: {
>      card: {
>        installments: null,
>        mandate_options: null,
>        network: null,
>        request_three_d_secure: 'automatic'
>      },
>      cashapp: {},
>      link: { persistent_token: null }
>    },
>    payment_method_types: [ 'card', 'link', 'cashapp' ],
>    processing: null,
>    receipt_email: null,
>    review: null,
>    setup_future_usage: null,
>    shipping: null,
>    source: null,
>    statement_descriptor: null,
>    statement_descriptor_suffix: null,
>    status: 'requires_payment_method',
>    transfer_data: null,
>    transfer_group: null
>  }
```

Then in the frontend, I am calling it

```
            customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKeyData.secret, // ek_test_xxxxxxx
            customerId,     // cus_xxxxx
            merchantDisplayName: 'my name',
            paymentIntentClientSecret: intent.paymentIntent, //pi_xxxxxxx
            customFlow: false,
            style: 'automatic'
        });

        const paymentResponse = await presentPaymentSheet();
```

But, the checkbox does not show.
[image]

I found another post [How to get the "Save Card Details" option from stripe's paymentSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74105664/how-to-get-the-save-card-details-option-from-stripes-paymentsheet) that says to not enable the `setup_future_usage` on server, but I am not referrencing that at all in my back end code.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see the same thing when testing with Android and iOS? What do you see if you don't set `automatic_payment_methods` when creating the PaymentIntent and instead set `payment_method_types: ['card']`?

Comment: Tried your suggestion of removing `automatic_payment_methods` and adding `payment_method_types: ['card']`.  Still don't see the checkbox.

Comment: If that's not working then it's likely that something is wrong with your code that's setting the ephemeral key/customer (or maybe it's something specific to your PaymentIntent) - have you checked that the ephemeral key and customer ID values look correct and you're not seeing any errors in your logs? If nothing is standing out you'll probably want to just ask Stripe's support team (https://support.stripe.com/contact) for some help narrowing down the issue

Comment: The payment goes through successfully once I fill out the card info and press pay.  Just isn't saved to the customer.  The customer is saved, but no default payment type when I look at the stripe admin.

Comment: And yes - same thing on android as ios similator I have running.